# pass files through php with rename

Tags: php, image

I have 1600 images, each 256px. These images have been sliced in photoshop from an image that is 10240px x 10240px in to the tiles. Problem is, photoshop has named them image_0001.png, image_0002.png...

I would like to rename these in to a usable file name such as image_x_y.png x being tile number in that row, y being tile number in that column...

And ideas how i can automate the renaming of these, or if not how i can pass these images through php, so that i can access image.php?x=2&y=1 ect...

thanks in advance

EDIT:
I have no permission to answer my own question but, used this as renaming would be required on every update. Not ideal...

```
<?php
$x=$_GET['x'];
$y=$_GET['y'];
$image=(($y-1)*40)+$x;
if ($image<10){
$image="0".$image;
}
$url="tiles/" . $image . ".jpg";

header("Location:" . $url);
?>
```

Comment: I guess that image_0001 is the top left tile. Is image_0002 to the "right" of 0001 or "below"?

Answer (score 1):

You could open the directory containing your files and then create a loop to access all images and rename them, like:

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/image/directory')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        //do the renaming here
        //$newName = 
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Useful functions:

[`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php),[`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to rename them, just calculate the "linear id" on every access.

so, assuming you have a 40 * 40 set of files, in image.php you'd have something like

```
$fileid = $x * 40 + y;
$filename = sprintf("image_%04d.png",$fileid);
// send the file with name $filename
```

What formula you need depends on how it was sliced, could as well be `$y * 40 + x`

The main advantage is that should your image be updated, it will be ready to use without the intermediate step of renaming the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$dir = "your_dir";
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$col = 5;
foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) 
{ 
    rename($file, "image"."_".$j."_".$i);
    $i++;
    if($i % $col == 0)
    {
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the routine that converted your files always named the resulting images in the same order 
i.e. top left = 0001 ...... Bottom right = 0016

Then it should be fairly simple to write a quick CLI script to go through and rename all your images.

Alternatively if you are going to use that same image converter again many times it may be simpler to make your image.php?x=1&y=2 script workout what file to serve then you wont need to do the renaming every time you get new images.

Answer (score 0):

-read the soure folder with your images (http://php.net/manual/de/function.readdir.php)

-put the part of each imagename between "_" and "."

-parse it ($image_nr) as integer

-do the following:

```
$y = floor($image_nr/40);
$x = $image_nr%40;
```

finaly put each image in your destination directory with the new name

Answer (score 0):

I Have not tested it but you could try using this:

```
$imagesInARow = 10240/256; //=> 40
$rows = 1600 / $imagesInARow; //=> 40

$imageIndex = 1;
for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) { // row iteration
    for($j = 1; $j <= $imagesInARow; $j++) { // columns iteration
        rename('image_'. str_pad($imageIndex, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'.png',
               "image_{$i}_{$j}.png");
        $imageIndex ++;
    }
}
```